# Laurent series expansion of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have $$f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z}$$ and I am trying to find the Laurent series expansion of this around the point $$z=i$$ in the domain D $$|z-i| \geq \sqrt2$$

I know the answer is $$\frac{1}{z-i} \sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^n \left(\frac{1+i}{z-i}\right)^n$$

How do I get this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean a Laurent series expansion near $z=i$.

You may write, as $|z - i| > \sqrt{2}$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{1+z}&=\frac1{(z-i)+(1+i)}\\\\
&=\frac1{(z-i)}\frac1{1+\dfrac{1+i}{z-i}}\\\\
&=\frac1{(z-i)}\sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^n \left(\frac{1+i}{z-i}\right)^n
\end{align}
$$ where we have just used
$$
\frac1{1+u}=\sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^n u^n, \quad |u|<1,
$$ setting $\displaystyle u=\frac{1+i}{z-i}, \, |u|<1$.

Comment: How did you know to write $\frac{1}{1+z}$ as $\frac{1}{(z-i)+(1+i)}?$ I thought it had to be put into the standard geometric form of $\frac{1}{1-z}$

Comment: @Aljabra Because the Laurent series was asked near $z-i$, so I wrote $z+1=(z-i)+(1+i)$ and factored $z-i$. If you consider $\frac1{1-u}$ instead, it amounts to the same result, since you get $\sum u^n=\sum (-1)^n (-u)^n$. Hoping to be clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind writing out the method for considering $\frac{1}{1-u}$?

Comment: @Aljabra You may write $$
\begin{align}
\frac1{1+z}&=\frac1{(z-i)+(1+i)}\\\\
&=\frac1{(z-i)}\frac1{1-\left(-\dfrac{1+i}{z-i}\right)}\\\\ &=\frac1{(z-i)}\frac1{1-u}\\\\ &=\frac1{(z-i)}\sum^\infty_{n=0} \left(-\frac{1+i}{z-i}\right)^n\\\\
&=\frac1{(z-i)}\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^n \left(\frac{1+i}{z-i}\right)^n
\end{align}
$$ obtaining the same result.

Comment: Thank you so much. Fantastic answer